# How to change data source of a table based on selection from another table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view which contain 3 tables

1-First

2-second

3-third

I have tried `UISplitView` view but as many post says it is only supports 2 views, so I have decided to move to 3 table chose

I want to change the data source of second table based on user click on first table

here is my code :
first

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test",@"20",@"30",@"40",@"5",@"6",@"6",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",nil];
    SecondViewController *s=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [s setitems:items];

}
```

in second

```
-(void) setitems :(NSMutableArray *)datasource
{
    items=datasource;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

the problem is `numberOfRowsInSection` for the second table do not get fired?
I want to know the best way to change table datasource dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the second tableview's delegate to self? Else the tableview's delegate methods wont get called.

Comment: I have UItableviewController which is by default set delegates to self

Comment: ok, try setting the datasource after pushing to the second view.

Comment: both tables in the same view

Comment: maybe u need to call `[self setttems:items];` then. Why are u doing `[s setttems:items];` ?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView delegates gets fired only if tableView is loaded(visible on view). You are initializing SecondViewController but table will get loaded. It will load when you access(or display) SecondViewController's view. So try calling [s setitems:items]; after adding SecondViewController's view.